# Unable to set div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Currently working with jquery drag and drop, I have two div `draggable` on left side and `droppable` on right side. I have two elements in draggable div from where I am able to drag and drop into droppable div

But what I need is that when I am dropping the an element into droppable div then the id of the droppable div should be changed.

How can I change the id of the elemets of right div and the id of left div should be same..

Here is my jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucerturohit/zHZxp/4/)

Comment: you want to change the target div`s id or the elments id which is being dropped to target div ?

Comment: Do you want the newly ID'd element to still be a drop target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var j="b_"+i;
    ui.draggable.attr("id",j);
    id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
    ....
```

You were modifying the draggable's ID, and then cloning it. Instead, you should be cloning it and then modifying the clone's ID.

I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/zHZxp/7/

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var j="b_"+i;
    $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone().attr("id",j));
    ....
```